# Invalid bracketing of name error in ado connection to csv

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I'm trying to do a select from a csv file via ADO from excel/vba. I have a connection to a csv set up, and am attempting to do the select via a recordset (rs).

My csv file has the name "B1-D D_20150915_12345_[31-Aug-2015].csv" (name generated by some other system, I can't change this)

my select / rs.open look like this:

```
 sql = "select * from '" & strFileName & "' where [Company Code] = 'GBHQ'"
 sql = sql & " and  [Item Type] = 'BAL'"

 Call rs.Open(sql, cn, adOpenKeyset)
```

This give the following sql:

```
 select * from B1-D D_20150915_12345_[31-Aug-2015].csv where [Company Code] = 'GBHQ' and  [Item Type] = 'BAL'
```

When I run this, I get an error message saying:

```
 Unable to import Data
 Invalid bracketing of name "B1-D D_20150915_12345_[31-Aug-2015].csv"
```

The error is definitely associated with the filename, as if I change it to something like 'text.csv' then the rs.open works fine.

I can see that there are all kinds of objectionable characters in that filename - I can't change them without copying / renaming the file somewhere else which I don't want to do as it's rather large.

I'm hoping it's just some very simple knowledge that I don't have - is there anyway I can escape the filename? Or get it through some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double quotes around the worksheet name because it has a space in it

```
sql = "select * from '" & """" & strFileName & """" & "' where [Company Code] = 'GBHQ'"
sql = sql & " and  [Item Type] = 'BAL'"

Call rs.Open(sql, cn, adOpenKeyset)
```

or you might need brackets around it.

```
sql = "select * from '[" & strFileName & "]' where [Company Code] = 'GBHQ'"
sql = sql & " and  [Item Type] = 'BAL'"

Call rs.Open(sql, cn, adOpenKeyset)
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I'm getting similar errors for both of those:

Comment: Sorry - internet is playing up at work . Putting " around the entire filename and [] around it both yield similar errors.

Comment: I would still bet that it has to do with the space in that filename. Have you tried brackets with and without single quotes?

Comment: I'm sure somebody will point you in the right direction. If you don't find an answer, I can show you have to manually build you recordset and populate it by reading the data up from the worksheet. Not ideal since you said it is large. It could take some time depending on how large.

Comment: I have. I've removed the "[" from the file, so it's name becomes "B1-D D_20150915_12345_31-Aug-2015.csv". This then works with [] around it. Reintroducing the [] in the filename and it stops again - it looks like the second "]" in the filename makes it think that that's the end of the filename. Any thoughts on how to escape that one character?

Comment: Thanks for the offer - I'm sql'ing out of the csv as it's got too many rows to open in excel.

Comment: Have you tried ["filename"]? maybe it wants the brackets and need the "s to negate the inner [].

Comment: Can you temporarily rename the file?

Comment: I think I may do this - copy it and rename. Other people use it and rely on the name format, so I can't rename. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good call, but that's actually what I'm replacing with this change. Getting it in was ok but filtering of the text file line by line was too slow.